# iptables: MultiWAN and portforwarding & port redirection

Tags: iptables, firewall, gentoo, nat

I'm running Gentoo Linux, so using plain iptbales to manage my firewall and networking.
I usually use wan0 for all my traffic, but since I have already a web-server behind that i would like wan1 (bind to another domain) for my second web-server.

I have three interfaces:

- eth0 = LAN
- wan0 = Primary used WAN (default gateway)
- wan1 = Secondary WAN

Some Infos about the Gateways

```
> route -n 

Kernel IP Routentabelle
Ziel Router          Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         80.108.x.x      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wan0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
80.108.x.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U     0      0        0 wan0
84.114.y.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wan1
127.0.0.0       127.0.0.1       255.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 lo
```

The default init for NAT/MASQUEARDING is

```
sysctl -q -w net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1

iptables -N BLOCK
iptables -A BLOCK -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A BLOCK -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A BLOCK -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -i lo -j ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -s 192.168.0.0/16 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wan0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wan1 -j MASQUERADE
```

Behind this gateway I'm running several web-servers. On one machine I'm running a HTTP Server on Port 8000 instead of 80. Usually when I'm using wan0 as the incoming interface I use the following rules:

```
lan_host1="192.168.0.200"
iptables -A FORWARD -i wan0 -p TCP -d $lan_host1--dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wan0 -p TCP --dport 8000 -j DNAT --to-destination "$lan_host1":80
iptables -A FORWARD -i wan0 -p UDP -d $lan_host1--dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wan0 -p UDP --dport 8000 -j DNAT --to-destination "$lan_host1":80
```

That works fine.
Now I would like wan1 to be used, as wan0 is tied to an IP/domain I usually use for something else.

I thought a simple change to wan1 would do it.

```
lan_host1="192.168.0.200"
iptables -A FORWARD -i wan1 -p TCP -d $lan_host1--dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wan1 -p TCP --dport 8000 -j DNAT --to-destination "$lan_host1":80
iptables -A FORWARD -i wan1 -p UDP -d $lan_host1--dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i wan1 -p UDP --dport 8000 -j DNAT --to-destination "$lan_host1":80
```

But that doesn't work. I guess the issue is that wan0 is the default GW. So I guess packages received by wan1 are forwarded to lan_host1, but when being send back to the gateway they are send through wan0 instead of wan1 or at least using the ip from wan0.

Any suggestions how I could manage this?

Thanks in advance,
Rob

Comment: What I can tell: The packages are received on the firewall via the wan1 interface, but are not forwarded to the internal server...

Comment: Not relevant to your question, but anyway, what's the goal of `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -s 192.168.0.0/16 -j MASQUERADE`? Is that about hairpinning? Just curious.

Comment: @A.B it was or is part of a more complex setup (another tun0, VPN, etc...) But yes It's also used for hairpinning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the answer is tied to the configuration, I make some assumptions. You'll have to adapt the answer to fit the actual configuration.

- *wan1*'s LAN and gateway for *wan1* arbitrarily chosen as 84.114.7.0/24 and 84.114.7.254.
- no consideration of firewall rules made, but all this shouldn't interact with them.

On Linux [`ip link`](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/ip-link.8), [`ip address`](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/ip-address.8) and [`ip route`](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/ip-route.8) should always be used instead of deprecated `ifconfig` and `route`. `route` probably can't handle additional routing tables anyway.

Just as a reminder, *iptables* or actually *netfilter*, doesn't route, but it can by its actions alter routing decisions made by the IP routing stack. This [schematic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netfilter#/media/File:Netfilter-packet-flow.svg) shows where routing decisions can happen. For routed (rather than locally originated) traffic that's only in one place and alterations must happen before: *raw/PREROUTING*, *mangle/PREROUTING* or *nat/PREROUTING*, with *raw* often impractical, and *nat* only for limited cases, mostly leaving *mangle*.

A [basic multi-homed system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multihoming#Multihoming_with_multiple_addresses), to use multiple paths to internet, usually requires [policy routing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_routing), where the route can change not only with the destination as usual, but also with the source or with other selectors (as will be done here) used in policy rules. On Linux additional rules made with [`ip rule`](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/ip-rule.8) can select a different routing table to select for example a different default route (there will still be only one default route, but one *per routing table*).

So here the principle, while still keeping active [Strict Reverse Path Forwarding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3704#section-2.2) ([*rp_filter*](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt?h=v5.4#n1225)), is to accept packets coming from *wan1* and route them as usual toward *eth0* using an alternate table (which will allow to pass *rp_filter*). This additional routing table should duplicate the main routing table, but using only routes needed for the alternate path (*wan1*) and thus not including the usual routes with the "normal" path (*wan0*). If other routes (such as VPNs etc.) have to be involved in flows going through *wan1*, chances are that their route too have to be added, or other additional rules and tables have to be created to cope with that.

Since Linux discontinued the use of a routing cache in kernel 3.6, nothing in the routing stack would tell to send back reply packets from *host1* to the client through *wan1* and they would end up going out using the main default route through *wan0*, NATed with the wrong IP for this interface (*netfilter* is route-agnostic and had already chosen the NAT to be done when receiving the first packet of the connection) and probably dropped by the next router of the ISP also doing Strict Reverse Path Filtering. There's a *netfilter* feature allowing to copy a packet's mark in the conntrack's mark and put it back in the packet: this will act as route memory for the connection. So *iptables* and *netfilter*'s *conntrack* will be used for two related features: to mark the packet in order to alter the routing decision, and to restore this mark on the reply packets identified as part of the same connection.

All this translates to these commands:

- routing part

Use for marked packets (arbitrary mark value 101) an extra routing table (unrelated arbitrary value also 101) :

```
    ip rule add fwmark 101 lookup 101
```

Populate the table with entries similar the *main* routing table, minus *wan0* entries:

```
    ip route add table 101 192.168.0.0/16 dev eth0
    ip route add table 101 84.114.7.0/24 dev wan1
    ip route add table 101 default via 84.114.7.254 dev wan1
```

- *iptables*/*netfilter* part

There are various optimizations possible in the following commands, It can probably be improved.

Restore a potential previous mark already saved, so reply packets will get the same mark as original packets:

```
    iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
```

Mark packets arriving from *wan1* to alter routing decision above:

```
    iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i wan1 -j MARK --set-mark 101
```

If there's a mark, save it in *conntrack* (could have been done in the *nat* table to do it only once per connection flow rather than for every packet):

```
    iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -m mark ! --mark 0 -j CONNMARK --save-mark
```

Actually this will still fail a *Strict Reverse Path Forwarding* check, since this [undocumented feature](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/?h=v2.6.32.8&id=ecb7287c5f53747767efa0f0e844da69a6ec3a51) was added in 2010. It must be used here:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.wan1.src_valid_mark=1
```

Comment: Hi! You are right, i really should start using the `ip` command instead of the old ones. Anyway. As i haven't used multiple routing tables yet, the output was just to show what's currently there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It was exactly what i was looking for. The only thing I need to fix now is that also some specific source/ports combos shall also be routed over that.